# A question about "closed" shapes, like the sphere, in higher dimensions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm not sure of the appropriate term, so I'd like to use an imprecise definition and ask for help with the actual term and some of its properties:

A sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is "closed", in the sense that I'm using, in that it divides that space into a finite region "inside" the sphere and an infinite region "outside".

a) Is there a precise term and definition of the word "closed", especially in arbitrary Euclidean dimensions, that I'm using?  I see that a closed manifold might do what I want, but I feel that there are subtleties to the definition of closed manifold that might prevent me from saying "all closed manifolds define a finite inner region".

b) I am primarily interested in building more complex shapes from "closed" primitives.  Is it fair to say that "a finite sum of shapes of this class is also a shape in this class"?  Is that question too broad without a finite definition?

I am working only in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I don't consider special cases arising from more general fields.

Comment: Jordan's theorem might be relevant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem

Comment: ... or the generalisation to higher dimensions, the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem. I think the closest term to the property you are describing is "bounded".